# Jquery table column sliding effect

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slideshow

I will need a Jquery script for a table sliding effect just like

http://sfsdirectdemo.projects.sourceflow.com/luke  (middle plan table)

I Google it but have not any good result, anyone please help.

Comment: Why not look at the code for the site you mentioned?  If you want the exact same effect, then you have a perfect example to examine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example that I believe does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/nheldman/GB7Hc/3/

The trick is to create an *outer* div with the width of the table you want to show, and an *inner* div that is the width of **all** of the columns that could be displayed if you slide.

Then you can just use jQuery animate() to scrollLeft the *outer* container by the width of each column.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Noah, one more thing, is that possible for you to tweak the codes so if previous/next link reaches the first/last column then they become hidden? Just like the sample I posted, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much Noah, although you code has a bug but I have figured out myself, I really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a very similar thing at one point.  Here is a jsfiddle that I used to figure out the code.  Hop it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/mstarkman/U7JHM/9/