# Is there a jQuery GRID component that allows the first N columns to be fixed, while the other columns scroll horizontally

Tags: jquery, excel, grid

I am looking for a jQuery GRID component with Excel like editing that allows me to fix the first N columns and then allow the rest to scroll horizontally.

It absolutely has to be a jQuery component.

I've checked out the other answers to this here on stackoverflow but they are definitely not good enough - they don't support Excel like editing.
Here's what I checked out:

- [HTML/jQuery Tables: Scroll horizontally, fix the first (left) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030797/html-jquery-tables-scroll-horizontally-fix-the-first-left-column)
- [HTML table with horizontal scrolling (first column fixed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402295/html-table-with-horizontal-scrolling-first-column-fixed)

There were others but they didn't even come close.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at jQuery DataTables. It supports one or more fixed columns.

- This is an example which has one fixed column: [Example 1](http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/)
- This is an other example which has two fixed columns: [Example 2](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/two_columns.html)
- This is an editing example: [Example 3](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html)

jqGrid also supports these features. Here is its [demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the same type of thing and found very few solutions and the ones I did find either had issues or seemed hard to work with for things like editing.

So I rolled my own and learned a lot about browser reflows (speed), and dom manipulation. I needed to display 200-300 rows and 58 columns with a fixed header and x number of fixed left columns.  Some solutions just got downright sluggish when trying to edit or scroll.

I used the jQuery UI Widget factory pattern for my code. So far it supports sorting, cell renderers, row numbering, row select modes, and events for before/after edit render.

You can check out a fairly recent test at http://chronosrealty.com/fcTable/fcTable.html and steal the code as needed if it works for you. Cells are editable starting at column '11/5'. Still adding features and restructuring and hope to make it available with documentation sometime soon.